# Extract a set of digits from a string column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, extract

I am trying to extract a fixed-length digits from a string column in MySQL, how can I go about doing so? The usual like and regexp doesn't work, so am pretty certain a function is needed, but unsure where to start and how to go about writing one.

Please advise.

The fixed-length digits are 10 digits and a sample of the string column:

```
'SGD0.00 AUTOMSG:'0179187381' is near Esso @ 23:59.'
```

Please be advised the location of the 10 digits in the string varies.

Comment: what is your expected output of given string?

Comment: have a look at the SUBSTRING function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/string-functions.html

Comment: Are the strings fixed format (ie the numbers are _always_ in the same exact character position)?

Comment: no the location varies. its just a sample of one of the string. the expected output is the 0179187381

Comment: can you provide some more sample strings which will probably be in the table, since extracting digit from a random string is pretty difficult unless there is a pattern and just fixed length of 10 is not enough. So if there is a common pattern then it would be easy to find a mysql solution.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty - there is no pattern. the location of the digits are random in the string. so, if am not mistaken after a couple of days of research I have came up with the conclusion that a function + regexp is needed?

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
Just use: SUBSTR(str,x,y)
where:- str -> String,
        x -> position,
        y -> length
```

Example: **SELECT SUBSTR('ABCDEFG',2,3);** -> BCD

For more information visit this link:
 http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select substr("'SGD0.00 AUTOMSG:'0179187381' is near Esso @ 23:59.'", 19,10);
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| substr("'SGD0.00 AUTOMSG:'0179187381' is near Esso @ 23:59.'", 19,10) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0179187381                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.48 sec)
```

Comment: and what if the string is randon and the digit does not start from 19th position ?

Comment: If it preceded by a fixed string, you can use Verma's suggestion.  If you just need to find 10 digits in a row, you need one of the regexp user-defined functions.

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Quadratically',5);
```

Syntax:  `SUBSTRING(str,pos)`

For more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Answer (score 0):

If the 10 digit number will always be preceeded with `:'` then you could use:

```
select substr(column_name, locate(":'", column_name) + 2, 10) from table_name
```

(assuming `:'` does not appear anywhere else before the number in the string)

Comment: Thanks for the input @Verma but - like i said in the original post, the 10 digit number location is random in the string of the column.

Comment: This statement will take care of random placement; all it assumes is that the 10 digit number has the string `:'` immediately before it. The number can be anywhere in the string.

Comment: I know that, the thing is the assumption made (assuming :' is immediately before it) is wrong. @Verma

Comment: ah, ok. In that case regex would be the only option in my opinion